# mysql count with 0

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables, a table Months and a table Ad. I would like to return all distinct emails from Ad per month.

Table Ad : created_at is a DATETIME.

Table Months  : id_month (INT and primary key)

[image]

I tried with a left join :

```
SELECT Months.id_month,count(distinct Ad.email)
FROM `Months` left outer join `Ad` 
ON  id_month = MONTH(Ad.created_at)
GROUP BY id_month
ORDER BY id_month ASC
```

But there is no result for december and it doesn't return 0. (only results for months from 1 to 11)

Any idea?

I found that if I add this condition :

```
WHERE YEAR(Ad.created_at)=2015
```

then it doesn't return 0 for december.. why?

Comment: Are you sure that months table have `december(12)` month

Comment: what do you mean, yes the table months contain 12 rows, including december (I've updated with a printscreen of table months)

Comment: Works here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69302/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on OP's comments on *@Dhaval Asodariya* answer

You should move the filter on `Ad` to the `ON` condition of the `LEFT join` condition.

When you keep the right side table filter in `where` clause the `Left outer join` will be implicitly converted to `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT months.id_month, 
       Count(DISTINCT ad.email) 
FROM   `months` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `ad` 
                    ON id_month = Month(ad.created_at) 
                       AND Year(ad.created_at) = 2015 
GROUP  BY id_month 
ORDER  BY id_month ASC
```

Comment: ok, yes, right answer, solved. thank you very much. but why a "where" doen't work?

Comment: @Julien - In question always you should add the exact code that you are using

Comment: yes okay, I simply wanted to simplify this query, but you're right!

Comment: and just a last question, how I could get distinct emails but only "new emails" every month, not those who where "present" in the previous months?

Comment: @Julien - Ask a new question with sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Months.id_month,count(Ad.email) Emails 
FROM `Months` 
JOIN `Ad` ON  Months.id_month = MONTH(Ad.created_at)
GROUP BY Months.id_month
ORDER BY Months.id_month ASC
```

Comment: You Need to Add Column for Month in Ad Table because "JOIN `Ad` ON  Months.id_month = MONTH(Ad.created_at)"  is not worked

Comment: yes thank you VR46, I was looking that link, it works fine on Fiddle but doesn't work on my workbench, strange

Comment: @VR46 I found, if I add "where YEAR(Ad.created_at)=2015"  then there is no 0 for december, if I remove that cond, then it shows 0 for december, why?

Comment: @Julien - added answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Months.id_month,count(distinct Ad.email)
FROM `Months` left join `Ad` 
ON  id_month = MONTH(Ad.created_at)
GROUP BY id_month
ORDER BY id_month ASC
```

Comment: Use group by ad.created_at so that you will be able to findout what is happening it might help

SELECT Months.id_month,count(distinct Ad.email)
FROM `Months` left join `Ad` 
ON  id_month = MONTH(Ad.created_at)
GROUP BY MONTH(Ad.created_at)
ORDER BY id_month ASC

Answer (score 0):

Try by using if statement. I just checked in the [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69302/3) its working fine.

```
SELECT months.id_month, 
       IF(Count(DISTINCT ad.email), Count(DISTINCT ad.email), 0) 
FROM   `months` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `ad` 
                    ON id_month = Month(ad.created_at) 
GROUP  BY id_month 
ORDER  BY id_month ASC
```